# How to use large array size?

Tags: c++, data-structures, segment-tree

I was trying this problem on spoj. www.spoj.com/problems/RRANGE.It requires segment tree.But the problem is with the size of array.Here (1 <= N <= 1,000,000,000).Any way to work around this problem?
Here is my implementation(gives correct answer for nearly N<1000000)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
//segment tree
long long a[1000000];

long long Mid(long long s,long long e)
{
    return s+(e-s)/2;
}
long long Sum1(long long *st,long long ss,long long se,long long qs,long long qe,long long index)
{
    if (qs<=ss&&qe>=se)
        return st[index];
    if (se<qs||ss>qe)
        return 0;
    long long mid=Mid(ss, se);
    return Sum1(st,ss,mid,qs,qe,2*index+1) +Sum1(st,mid+1,se,qs,qe,2*index+2);
}
void update1(long long *st,long long ss,long long se,long long i,long long diff,long long index)
{
    if (i<ss||i>se)
        return;
    st[index]=st[index]+diff;
    if (se!=ss)
    {
        long long mid = Mid(ss,se);
        update1(st,ss,mid,i,diff,2*index+1);
        update1(st,mid+1,se,i,diff,2*index+2);
    }
}
void update(long long arr[],long long *st,long long n,long long i,long long new_val)
{
    if (i<0||i>n-1)
    return;
    long long diff = new_val - arr[i];
    arr[i] = new_val;
    update1(st,0,n-1,i,diff,0);
}
long long Sum(long long *st,long long n,long long qs,long long qe)
{
    if (qs<0||qe>n-1||qs>qe)
    return -1;
    return Sum1(st,0,n-1,qs,qe,0);
}

long long segtree(long long arr[],long long ss,long long se,long long *st,long long si)
{

    if (ss==se)
    {
        st[si]=arr[ss];
        return arr[ss];
    }


    long long mid=Mid(ss, se);
    st[si]=segtree(arr,ss,mid,st,si*2+1)+segtree(arr,mid+1,se,st,si*2+2);
    return st[si];
}

long long *segt(long long arr[],long long n)
{
    long long x = (long long)(ceil(log2(n)));
    long long max_size = 2*(long long)pow(2, x) - 1;
    long long *st = new long long[max_size];
    segtree(arr,0,n-1,st,0);
    return st;
}
int main()
{
    //memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
    long long n,u,v;
    cin>>n>>u>>v;
    for(long long i=0;i<n;i++)
    a[i]=0;
    long long *st=segt(a,n);


    while(u--)
    {
        long long i,j;
        cin>>i>>j;
        long long z=1;
        for(long long p=i-1;p<j;p++)
        {
        update(a,st,n,p,a[p]+z);
        z++;
        }
    //for(int m=0;m<n;m++)
    //cout<<a[m]<<endl;

    }
    while(v--)
    {
        long long i,j;
        cin>>i>>j;
        cout<<Sum(st,n,i-1,j-1)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is the specific problem with very large N?

Comment: For my opinion question is not well formulated. If you don't know the exact size of elements in array at compilation time then there are tools for this: std::vector - a container for any type of objects of the variable size. Using it is much safer and everyone is encouraged to use this standard, portable tool for managing arrays.

Answer (score 2):

In C or C++ local objects are generally or usually allocated on the stack. Since you are allocating a very large array on the stack. So you have a chance of getting a **stack overflow**. I would recommend you to use `std::vector<int>` and resize it to 1000000 elements.

Comment: Or a deque if the number of elements is to large for a single buffer.

Comment: Or enable segmented stacks?

Comment: Will vector be able to hold 1000,000,000 elements?

Comment: And what all changes have to be made in this code if i use vector?

Comment: please note that according to the question the elements may be as many as a billion

Answer (score 2):

Whatever solution you try you will need more than 8 GB of ram to solve the problem using this algorithm. Memory limit on spoj is way less. Think of an alternative solution that requires less memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `binary indexed tree` instead of a `segment tree`-> [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) is a nive tutorial.

A BIT takes O(n) memory, compared to a segment tree's O(2^(logN+2)), and it can serve the same purpose.

Hope this helps...